# Storing the value of variable in JS

Tags: javascript

*Since my main language is C, I am used to pointers and I love them. Now I have some project which I need to finish in Javascript and I've got a problem which I don't know how to solve.*

I want to store the value of a variable which I got from GET request. I have a script to send GET to PHP page, which then sends GET to my daemon written in C. When I get the string I wanted, I use `length` to measure the size of the string I got and in next GET request I want to send that number of bytes I got as the URL parameter.

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (bytes === undefined) {
    var bytes = 0;
  }
  var url = "/test/log.php?q=" + bytes;

  function httpGet(url) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.onload = function(e) {
      if (xhttp.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhttp.status === 200) {
          console.log(xhttp.responseText);
          var option = "";
          obj = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
          for (var key in obj) {
            option += obj[key];
          }

          document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = asdf;
          bytes = option.length;
        }
      };
      xhttp.onerror = function(e) {
        console.error(xhttp.statusText);
      }
    };

    xhttp.send();
  }

  var updateInterval = 2000;

  function update() {
    httpGet(url);
    setTimeout(update, updateInterval);
  }

  update();
}
```

So, the focus is on the variable `bytes`. It should have the value 0 when the script is a first time called, and after every loop (it loops every 2 seconds, I didn't show the loop in the code) it should have the value of the previous length of received string.

Comment: Is page reloaded every 2 seconds?

Comment: *"I didn't show the loop in the code"* – well, you should.

Comment: @Juhana Alright I added it. What now?

Comment: @NuriTasdemir No it's not.

Comment: You set the variable `url` only once. It won't automatically change whenever `bytes` changes.

Comment: @Juhana Aight, I added the line url = "/test/log.php?q="+bytes; after bytes = option.length; still nothing changes.

Comment: If you move `url = "/test/log.php?q="+bytes;`  inside your `function httpGet(url) { }` function and didn't change the parameter name `url` then the changes are shallowed by the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure to add the bytes param onto your url in a way that changes with each call rather than just once at page load when it will always be 0.

```html
window.onload = function() {
  if (bytes === undefined) {
    var bytes = 0;
  }
  var url = "/test/log.php?q=";

  function httpGet(url) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.onload = function(e) {
      if (xhttp.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhttp.status === 200) {
          console.log(xhttp.responseText);
          var option = "";
          obj = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
          for (var key in obj) {
            option += obj[key];
          }

          document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = asdf;
          bytes = option.length;
        }
      };
      xhttp.onerror = function(e) {
        console.error(xhttp.statusText);
      }
    };

    xhttp.send();
  }

  var updateInterval = 2000;

  function update() {
    httpGet(url + bytes);
    setTimeout(update, updateInterval);
  }

  update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a fixed value of url make it to a function and it will give you always the current Url with the modified version of bytes, if you modify it

You have only to change this parts

```
var url = ...
// to 
function getUrl() {
  return "/test/log.php?q=" + bytes;
}

...
// and 
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
// to
xhttp.open("GET", getUrl(), true);
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all. Doesn't even send GET requests.

Comment: Well, I'm not stupid. I know, I changed it and it simply doesn't work. But nvm, the answer above solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I'd declare the variable in a context that doesn't empty its value when the function is called. So, you can declare your variable "bytes" before the function, and then looping through that function. In this case, the variable will hold the last value until you overwrite it.

That should work!

Comment: I think I already did that with   
if (bytes === undefined) {
  var bytes=0;
  }

Comment: Nope. You have to declare the variable outside the function, not inside it. This way, variable's scope ends when the function call ends, so it will not be accesible from a second loop to that function.

Comment: Found the solution. Thanks anyway.